# AngularJS View Animation Mystery—elements render at wrong position then resolve

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, sass, ng-animate

Working with angular and using animate.css to handle some animations that get applied to views as they enter and leave. I've come into a problem that has eluded my attempts to solve it thus far.

**What I'm after**: Getting various elements to slide in/out as if you're panning across

**The problem**: While the actual animations work just fine, the view change renders them with an offset so that they don't appear to be sliding. After a second the correct styles get applied, but I can't tell why. I've looked at the docs for ng-animate, tried deactivating modules, and isolating the problem in other ways but can't seem to figure it out.

*Misc.*:

- I'm using animate.css to handle the transitions, but that doesn't seem to be the culprit as the transitions work 'normally'/as they should in some cases (on refresh, on direct URL load)
- this appears to be a reflow, which happens sometimes on href nav but not on refresh. Tried tracking this down in the ng-animate docs but I can't make out why/how it only seems to happen on href nav from links and not on a refresh (something to do with template cacheing?)
- doesn't seem to be browser-specific
- haven't seen any questions anywhere on SO or elsewhere talking about this, so resources work as in addition to answers

I can include more code once someone has an idea of what area might be causing the problem.  Don't want to include the entire project at first :)

Using: 
everything 1.2.21

- angular
- ngAnimate
- ngMocks
- resource
- sanitize

Here's what happens:
(note: the second command I give is a refresh, where the animation happens normally)

[image: explanation]

Some initial code:

I use this mixin to handle the `.ng-enter` and similar classes

```
  @import "../bower_components/animate.css/animate.sass";
  @mixin panInner($direction, $LeftOrRight) {
      @extend .animated;
      @extend  .slide#{$direction}#{$LeftOrRight};
  }

  @mixin pan{
    .ng-enter, .ng-enter-active {
      @include panInner(In, Right);  

        }
    .ng-leave, .ng-leave.ng-leave-active  {
      @include panInner(Out, Left);    
    }
    .ng-enter-active, .ng-leave-active {
      animation-duration: 2s;
    }  
  }


  @include pan;
```

This is for a project I've been really close-up to for a long while now, so it's always possible that I've missed something dumb, but I hope not.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are animating the pages in `Position: relative` rather than `Position: absolute`.

So what this means is that as the first section animates out, the second section still thinks it's there "above" it and is offset downwards accordingly until the first section has completed its animation and is removed from the DOM.

With `Position: absolute` the page element being animated in won't care about the previous sibling element being animated out. Just keep in mind that both should be inside of the same wrapper element with a relative or absolute position so that they don't jump up when switching to `Position: absolute`.